# Recursive javascript for nested comments

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to recursively loop through nested comment data such as...

```
-parent comment a
----child comment a
--------grandchild comment a
----child comment b
-parent comment b
```

And here's the outline of what I'm doing in javascript...

```
loadChildComments(commentdata[i].comment_id); //for every parent comment I make this call to load children

function loadChildComments(parentId){

  for (k=0; k<commentdata.length; k++) { //loop through the same data set looking for child comments
    if (commentdata[k].immediate_parent_id == parentId) {
      //we've found a child comment

      //bunch of steps to add the child comment to the page

      ///just finished adding a child comment so loop through to see if that child itself has children
      loadChildComments(commentdata[k].comment_id); //also tried arguments.callee(commentdata[k].comment_id);

    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

If I don't add the recursive callback to loadChildComments() at the end, I correctly get...

```
-parent comment a
----child comment a
----child comment b
-parent comment b
```

But when I do include the callback I get this...

```
-parent comment a
----child comment a
--------grandchild comment a
-parent comment b
```

(missing "child comment b")

So it seems the recursive call is working, but javascript doesn't pick up where it previously was when it finishes the recursive call?

Pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental about the way recursive loops work in javascript but no idea what after doing a little research and trying various solutions to no avail.  Thanks for any ideas whatsoever!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For recursion to work like this, you must declare the `k` variable to be a local variable.  Otherwise it is an implicit global and every recursive call to the function overwrites the value of that variable that the caller was using so when you return from a recursive call, the value of `k` in the parent caller has been destroyed and its loop fails to do what it is supposed to.  See the `var` added to the `k` definition here:

```
loadChildComments(commentdata[i].comment_id); //for every parent comment I make this call to load children

function loadChildComments(parentId){

  // <== Add var in front of k=0 in line below
  for (var k=0; k<commentdata.length; k++) { //loop through the same data set looking for child comments
    if (commentdata[k].immediate_parent_id == parentId) {
      //we've found a child comment

      //bunch of steps to add the child comment to the page

      ///just finished adding a child comment so loop through to see if that child itself has children
      loadChildComments(commentdata[k].comment_id); //also tried arguments.callee(commentdata[k].comment_id);

    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

If you run your code in strict mode, then this type of mistake will be an error and the runtime will immediately point it out to you.  Implicit globals (when you fail to declare a variable) are a bad feature of Javascript.  Use strict mode to prevent them.

Comment: oh man, thanks so much for catching that and explaining the problem (I blame Java for making me write bad javascript!)  accepting the answer shortly...